# Hide Dojo floating pane when click on close button

Tags: html, dojo

I have dojo floating page. when I click on image that pane should pop up. The thing is when I make closable true and hit on the close button this ***detail*** div removing from HTML DOM. I want to hide the element with the close button not to remove from the div.

Here with I have attached the code snipe in JSP page.

```html
<div dojoType="dojox.layout.FloatingPane" region="center" data-dojo-props="title: 'Detail',resizable:true,closable:true,dockable: false " closable="true" id="detail" class="overlay_content">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="text-align: center;" id="detailDiv"></div>
</div>
```